# Change date in element with jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using the jQuery datepicker for a project of mine and it's working great except that I'm not able to change the date inside an element onSelect.

My code is as follows:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
   dateFormat: "d MM yy",
   onSelect: function(dateText) 
   { 
       var url = "/schedule_backend.php";
       var league = $('#compose').val();
       var data = "date="+ dateText +"&league="+ league;
       var myDate = new Date(dateText);
       var newFormat = $.format.date('dd M yy', myDate);                

       alert(newFormat);

       $("#kind").text(myDate);

   $('.schedule_block').load(url, data);                

   document.title = 'Sportannica - Schedule for '+ newFormat;           
  }
});
```

Nothing is being alerted when I select a date. Any ideas on how to format the date appropriately?

Thanks,

Lance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery does not format dates by default. You will need to download and use a plugin. However, it is not too hard to do it manually.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
dateFormat: "d MM yy",
onSelect: function(dateText) 
{ 
   var url = "/schedule_backend.php";
   var league = $('#compose').val();
   var data = "date="+ dateText +"&league="+ league;
   var d = new Date(dateText);

   var weekday=new Array(7);
   weekday[0]="Sunday";
   weekday[1]="Monday";
   weekday[2]="Tuesday";
   weekday[3]="Wednesday";
   weekday[4]="Thursday";
   weekday[5]="Friday";
   weekday[6]="Saturday";

   var month=new Array();
   month[0]="January";
   month[1]="February";
   month[2]="March";
   month[3]="April";
   month[4]="May";
   month[5]="June";
   month[6]="July";
   month[7]="August";
   month[8]="September";
   month[9]="October";
   month[10]="November";
   month[11]="December";

   var newFormat = weekday[d.getDay()] + ", " + month[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getDate();

   alert(newFormat);
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gEdmj/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem lies in your formatter... what are you using for it? Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KwXxc/) that shows that the function is being called, and the date is correct, but your formatter is nullifying it.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "d MM yy",
  onSelect: function(dateText)
  {
    var myDate = new Date(dateText);
    //var newFormat = $.format.date('dd M yy', myDate);
    var newFormat = myDate.toString();
    alert(newFormat);
  }
});
```

Comment: var newFormat is alerted as 'Wed Jan 16 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)'

Comment: Yes, my point is that if you use your formatter and the alert is blank, then it's the the call to `$.format.date(...)` that is the problem, not the datepicker UI plugin. So I would see if that formatter can accept your format, or if there is something else going in there.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what it's doing

Comment: If you point me to that plugin I can check it out, otherwise I'm not sure what else I can help with.